# How to automatically wrap long lines in emacs?

Tags: linux, emacs

I just tried Gnu emacs 23 automatic long line wrapping feature using M-x `auto-fill-mode`. it works perfectly. Now I modified my `.emacs` file as following to have this feature always turned on but it doesn't work ...

```
;;; Xemacs backwards compatibility file
(setq user-init-file
      (expand-file-name "init.el"
            (expand-file-name ".xemacs" "~")))
(setq custom-file
      (expand-file-name "custom.el"
            (expand-file-name ".xemacs" "~")))

(load-file user-init-file)
(load-file custom-file)
(global-linum-mode t)

;;; Scrollbar on the right
(set-scroll-bar-mode 'right)

;;; Open help file
(find-file "/home/manu/These/Docs/Emacs-Shortcuts")
(split-window-horizontally)

;;; Transparency
 ;;(set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha '(<active> [<inactive>]))
 (set-frame-parameter (selected-frame) 'alpha '(85 50))
 (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(alpha 85 50))

;;; Auto fill to wrap long lines
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Emacs FAQ](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/emacs-21.1/html_chapter/faq_5.html#SEC38) you can turn on auto-fill mode just for text-mode (for general text files)

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

If you want to enable auto-fill mode globally (for all modes) add this line to your ini file:

```
(setq-default auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)
```

Comment: Thanks !! Just one more question, I conclude that tex files (the ones I am working with now) are not considered as general text files. It sounds strange, no ?

Comment: No.Text mode is a major mode for editing files of text in a human language. Files which have names ending in the extension .txt are usually opened in Text mode [Emacs text-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Mode.html)

Comment: In your case it is most likely latex-mode which is default mode for editing tex/latex files in emacs

Answer (score 7):

Emacs 23 has [`visual-line-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visual-Line-Mode.html), which does not change the text, but instead wraps long lines on word boundaries when the buffer is displayed. For some kinds of document this is better than [`auto-fill-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Fill.html), which changes the text, and so loses the distinction between "soft" and "hard" line breaks.

You can automatically turn on `visual-line-mode` in the same way as `auto-fill-mode`, for example:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-visual-line-mode)
```